# Is it possible to password-lock Windows 10 only in my office?

Tags: windows-10, geolocation, lock

I work in a shared office and I use two computers: a desktop which stays in the office and locks with a password (running linux), and my personal laptop which I carry around with me (running Windows). I usually have them both on at any given time when I'm in the office.

I don't use a lock password on my laptop because I'm not worried about people having physical access to it out of the office and I'm lazy so I'd prefer not to have to type one. It also makes it easier to let my girlfriend or my family use it without telling them a password.

In this modern world of location-sensitive software I was wondering if there's any way to convince Windows 10 to lock with a password only when I'm at the office and not elsewhere. I have a 'lock' key on my keyboard that I press, which does the standard Windows lock (like pressing win+l) - ideally it would function the exact same way and I wouldn't have to press anything different at the office and elsewhere.

Here are my ideas so far for detecting location since my laptop doesn't have a GPS chip:

1) Based on the wifi network. (This might be an issue because I use [eduroam](https://www.eduroam.org/) in the office and around the city - I don't want a password lock when I'm using eduroam outside of the office).

2) Somehow communicating with my phone to get my location (assuming my phone and my laptop are in the same place).

Comment: I would personally recommend becoming less lazy and just setting up a password. Maybe create a separate account for your girlfriend/family too, while you're at it.

Comment: You already told us that you won't be able to use 1) as you're usually connected to the same network. So you'd have to check available SSIDs instead. Is there a WLAN at your workplace that's only up there? 2) would require you to connect your phone to your notebook or to write/use an app to exchange that information using the internet. Sounds like something that's is easy to break.

Comment: Windows 10 supports `Windows Hello`, which means you can use biometrics (face, fingerprint) by using a supported camera or fingerprint scanner.  This would offer you security, you can simply leave these devices at your office, and you could simply connect them at the office.  *Windows 10 does not have this feature your looking for built-in.*  It might not even exist in the third-party world, I don't actually know, but wouldn't be able to recommend a solution even if I did know.

Comment: @Seth yes indeed, there is a WLAN that I'll only see at the office